# Is it safe to include cobertura instrumentation in production builds?

Tags: java, performance, maven, instrumentation, cobertura

Our organization is mandating the generation of code coverage reports using the maven-cobertura-plugin, for all code that needs to go to production.

My understanding is that cobertura instruments the class files (modifies the bytecode) to enable calculation of code coverage. I have a few questions on how this works:

1) If I configure the build to run the instrumentation goal, and use the same build to generate the EAR for installation on the production appserver, will the modified bytecode end up being deployed?

2) If yes, will this cause any degradation in application performance due to the extra diagnostic code injected into the bytecode?

3) Is it advisable to have a separate build job setup for cobertura instrumentation and code coverage report generation, so that it does not pollute the code to be installed in production?

Your inputs are highly appreciated!

Comment: Normally, any code coverage plugin will generate instrumented classes in _another directory_ than the "production classes" directory to generate the coverage report; while I don't know how the bytecode is instrumented, my guess is that this instrumentation will prevent the JIT from performing its job, and as such you should avoid having such instrumented classes in production environments. Also, code coverage is not everything; you may also be interested in running [mutation testing](https://github.com/hcoles/pitest).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I think you're right, as I see classes being generated in a separate folder when the instrumentation task runs. However, we have decided to keep the instrumentation and report generation separate from our regular build, to keep them running faster.